# Finding index and size of consecutive repeated elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

An array consists of `1`, `2`, and `0`s. I am trying to identify the maximum repetition and its starting index within the array.

Example:

```
2 2 1 0 2 2 2 0 1 1
```

The method should accept an integer arguement, which can be one of the numbers `1` or `2`

If we demonstrate these inputs on above array, the outputs would be:

```
find_duplicates(2)
=>    3,4

find_duplicates(1)
=>    2,8
```

where the first number indicates the size of the duplication, and second is the starting index of it.

I tried looping through the array and compare with `arr[i+1]` or `arr[-1]`, but this is not the correct approach. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I had not pasted what I had tried at the time I asked the question, this is not something I would do if I could feel some confidence on the way I followed:

```
def find_status(arr,participant)
    status = Array.new
#arr is a two dimensional array
for i in 0...arr.length do
    current_line=arr[i]
    cons=0
    for j in 0...current_line.length do
         #I worked on lots of if/else/case statements here, this is just one of them
        if current_line[j] == participant
            cons+=1   #count consecutive
            if current_line[j]!=participant
                cons=0
            end
        end
        status[i] = cons
    end
end
return status
end
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "The method should accept the argument (1 or 2) and reply as below (input is 2):".

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That means "The method, should accept one of the two integers as inputs: "1" or "2".  And should return the described output

Comment: Hello @TobySpeight Sorry, that was my bad. I added the initial code I was working on. It looks I had lack of knowledge of the useful ruby methods to solve the problem. (especially `chunk`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def max_run(arr, target) 
  _,b = arr.each_with_index.
            chunk  { |n,_| n==target }.
            select { |tf,_| tf==true }.
            max_by { |_,a| a.size }
  b ? [b.size, b.first.last] : nil
end

arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]

max_run(arr,1) #=> [4, 6]
max_run(arr,2) #=> [4, 10]
max_run(arr,3) #=> [2, 14]
max_run(arr,4) #=> nil
```

For `target = 2`, the steps are as follows:

```
enum0 = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
  #    :each_with_index>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8],
  #     [1, 9], [2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13], [3, 14], [3, 15]]
```

Continuing,

```
enum1 = enum0.chunk  { |n,_| n==target }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f9beb9b0850>:each>
```

Carefully examine the return value here. You can think of `enum1` as a "compound enumerator". It will generate the following values:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[false, [[1, 0], [1, 1]]], [true, [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]],
  #    [false, [[3, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9]]],
  #    [true, [[2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13]]], [false, [[3, 14], [3, 15]]]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = enum1.select { |tf,_| tf==true }
  #=> [[true, [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]],
  #    [true, [[2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13]]]] 
_,b = c.max_by { |_,a| a.size }
  #=> [true, [[2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13]]] 
b #=> [[2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13]] 
b ? [b.size, b.first.last] : nil
  #=> [[2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13]] ? [4, [2,10].last]
  #=> [4, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed and well descripted response @Cary , it includes some parts which I never worked on before but I'll be digging it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1]

longest_sequence =
a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == 2}.chunk_while{|i, j| i.next == j}.max_by(&:length)
# => [4, 5, 6]

[longest_sequence.length, longest_sequence.first] # => [3, 4]
```

Comment: very clever answer, the composed array consists of the indexes of the desired occurance. easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is likely most efficient since it is `O(N)`. It walks through an array, collecting the chunks:

```
arr.each.with_index.reduce({idx:-1, i: -1, len: 0}) do |memo, (e, i)|
  memo[:i] = i if memo[:i] == -1 && e == 2        # at the beginning of chunk
  memo[:len], memo[:idx] = [i - memo[:i], memo[:i]] \
    if memo[:i] >= 0 && i - memo[:i] > memo[:len] # save values if needed
  memo[:i] = -1 unless e == 2                     # reset index counter
  memo
end.reject { |k, _| k == :i }                     # reject temporary index value

#⇒ {
#    :idx => 4,
#    :len => 3
#  }
```

To use it as method, accepting a parameter; just wrap the code above with `def find_duplicates number` and substitute `2` with number in the code above. Yes, it returns hash instead of an array.